# Complex logarithm and simply connected space

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, connectedness

I've got a problem to do something. Actually, we consider :

$U = \{ e^{s+it} \in \mathbb{C} \; | \; s,t \in \mathbb{R}, \; |s-t| < 1\}$,

We know that $U$ is an open and connected space, but first of all, I don't succeed to determine if $U$ is simply connected or not. Actually, I don't think so, but I don't know how to prove it. I thought about winding number, I would like to find two loop with different winding number, but I don't find out those loops...

Then, I have to show that it exists a complex logarithm on $U$ which verify that its value for $1$ is $2\pi i$, but I don't succeed to find which branch I have to cut... I have to play with the fact that $|s-t| < 1$ but how... ?

Thank you !

Edit : Actually, I don't have to cut a branch I think, because if I consider $e^{i\pi x}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, I have $e^{\pi x+i\pi x} = e^{\pi x}e^{i\pi x} \in U$, so I can't just cut a branch, I have to do another way...

Actually, for $z = e^{s+it}$, I can define : $f(z) = s+i(t+2\pi)$. $f$ is well-defined car if $e^{s+it}=e^{s'+it'}$, then $s=s'$ and $t = t'$ mod $2\pi$, so as we have $|s-t| < 1$, we must have $t=t'$. So $f$ is well-defined, and we can verify that $e^{f(z)}=z$, so it's okay, no ?

Comment: Let $V = \{ s + ti : s,t \in \mathbb{R}, \lvert s-t\rvert < 1\}$. Then $U = \exp(V)$. Now $\exp$ is holomorphic and locally injective, hence open. Is $\exp$ injective on $V$?

Comment: Yes it is, I think (I've edited my first post at the same time, is it the correct answer ?).

Comment: Hmmmfff. It's hard to tell whether some incorrect thinking has slipped into it. But it looks like you have the right idea. The presentation needs some work, however. // Yes, $\exp$ is injective on $V$, since $\exp(z) = \exp w \iff z-w \in 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$, and $2\pi > 2$. So $\exp\lvert_V \colon V \to U$ is a homeomorphism, consequently biholomorphic, and its inverse is a branch of $\log$ on $U$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much ! To show that $U$ is not simply connected, I use the fact that $\exp$ is injective on $V$, but not bijective, and as $f(V) = U$ is connected (by the open mapping theorem), I can find $z \in  \mathbb{C}$ but not in $U$ which verify that it exists $z' \in \mathbb{C}$ : $|z'| > |z|$ ans as $U$ is open, I can find a loop $\gamma$ (in U) which verify that the winding number of $z$ is 1, so $\gamma$ is not homotopic to a point. But it's not very formal for a proof... I just want to say that $U$ has a hole...

Comment: But $U$ is simply connected. It's homeomorphic to $V$.

Comment: Yes, I made a big mistake when I've said exp is injective from $V$ to $U$ but not bijective, of course it's bijective as $exp(V)=U$. So okay, it's alright. Thank you very much for your help !